# Unable to use variable value outside for loop in C program

Tags: c, loops

I am following a introductory C programming course and the first assignment is to find number of perfect squares in a given range.
I am trying to get the first perfect square root, but when I try to assign the first square root to a variable, i am unable to do so and it always shows 0.

This is the program that I have written:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float y= 0;
    float k = 1.0;
    float n;
    int i=0;
    int first_sqrt;
    first_sqrt = 0;

    printf("enter number: \n");
    scanf("%f",&n);

    // finding the first perfect square
    for(y = 0; y<=10000; y++)
        {
            while((k*k - n)>0.0001 || (n - k*k)> 0.0001)
            {
                k = (k + n/k) / 2;
                //printf("%f\n", k);
            }
            i = (int)k;
            if(i*i == n)
            {
                printf("perfect squareroot: %d\n", i);
                i = first_sqrt;
                y = 10001;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("not perfect square: %f\n", n);
                n = n+1;
            }
    }
    printf("first perfect square root: %d\n", first_sqrt);
}
```

I am sorry for posting the whole program, but I have no idea where the problem might be. This is the first assignment of the first week so I don't have understanding of a lot functions in C yet and I can't use math function for this assignment. 
Any help would be appreciated. Have been searching all day about this but couldn't understand much.

A basic direction towards the problem would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change `i = first_sqrt;` to `first_sqrt = i;`

Comment: I realize you are in an introductory course and that scanf seems to be all the rage in intro courses, but there is absolutely no need to prompt for a number and use scanf (which is an utterly horrible function for a beginner to be using) to read an input.  Pass the value as a command line argument, and parse argv (the second argument passed to main).  It will be far more useful for you to learn that technique.

Comment: Please try to get out of the bad habit of writing `void main` - it should be `int main`.

Comment: To further Paul's comment, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: thanks @WilliamPursell. The professor used it, so I used it. Read a bit about it just now, didn't understand quite a lot but seems void should not be used. Thanks for the heads up. Would keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `i = first_sqrt;` assigns `first_sqrt`to `i` and not `i` to `first_sqrt`. Change it to `first_sqrt = i;`. Apart from this you can remove the comment from `//break;`.

Comment: Thanks, working fine now. Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse this line

i = first_sqrt;

to    first_sqrt = i;

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up an assignment.  This:

```
i = first_sqrt;
```

Should be:

```
first_sqrt = i;
```

Comment: Thanks, got it now. Stupid mistake